# How do I hook into a currently running background thread to fetch its result?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.0, thread-safety

If there is a background thread running an operation, I'd like the UI thread to wait till its over and then get the result.

More details.  When I bring up a dialog box, users are interested in 2 pieces of information - let's call them `Info1` and `Info2`.  `Info1` takes 5 seconds to retrieve and `Info2` takes 15-30 seconds to retrieve.  In order not to annoy users, I initially fetch/display `Info1` and provide a button to get `Info2`.

When I fetch `Info1`, I kick off a background thread to fetch `Info2`.  The hope is that by the time the user presses a button for `Info2`, it will already have been fetched (and cached in a memory structure) and the user can see the information immediately.

The reality is that 90% of the time, the users press the `Info2` button prior to the background thread completing.

My question is this.  What is a good pattern to hook into the background thread at will and fetch its result when the operation is over?

Comment: As a general pattern, I would have the worker thread post its results as and when completed, so not "hooking in" to the worker thread at all, but posting to a data structure the UI can read on demand, or signalling to the UI. There are all sorts of options here. You could use synchronize access to a data structure (a sort of "mailbox"), or a class representing the worker thread could declare an event to which the UI could attach a handler, or the worker's "main" function could accept a delegate as a parameter which it would call to signal some event.

Comment: Looks like the flaw in your IDE.  The idea to grab an incomplete result from a thread that's working on obtaining it is a bit off the chart.  Look how BackgroundWorker can trickle results one by one through the ProgressChanged event.  Threads push, you don't pull.

Comment: @HansPassant The said functionality is several libraries removed from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.5 , take a look at async/await - they were designed right for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is how I solved the problem.  The solution is simple and non-patterny.  If I were starting from scratch, I would have probably used Futures as suggested by @agbinfo

```
private Thread thInfo2;

public Result GetData(Request request) {

    if (request.DataType == eDataType.Info2) {

        // if the request for Info2 is in progress already, wait a bit.
        while (thInfo2 != null && thInfo2.IsAlive)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Waiting");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }     

    // fire off the fetch
    Response response = svc.GetData(request)

    // kick off a secondary fetch if this request is for Info1
    if (request.DataType == eDataType.Info2) {
        thInfo2 = new Thread(FetchInfo2InBackground)
        {
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest,
            IsBackground = true
        };
        thInfo2.Start(request);  
    }     
}
```